# Count to numbers above a billion in a few seconds without browser freezing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a counter that counts to big numbers such as 6 billion (**like google's random number generator**) but the browser freezes.

```
var counter = document.querySelector("#blahblahblah");
var nb = 0;
var ne = 6_000_000_000;
for (;nb<=ne;nb++) {
counter.innerHTML = nb;
};
```

Comment: then don't do that - you don't count to 6 billion to generate a random number, you use `Math.random()` - if you want to count to 6 billion like that in less than a second, get a faster computer - also, updating the DOM 6 billion times like that is the same as updating it once, since the browser never gets a chance to actually display the updated DOM with a tight loop like that

Comment: also, JS engines can be quirky ... counting from 0 to 6 billion for example takes several times longer than counting from 10 billion to 16 billion (in firefox) - yet, it's still the same length loop! ... also, a loop like that in the global scope takes longer than if it's in a function - 4 times longer in firefox ... 20 times longer in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do is use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). This represents the fastest rate that you can update the DOM.

Use the callback to update your element text to the number proportional to the time allowed; 3 seconds (*a few*) from your question title

```js
const runCounter = (num, timeout, el) => {
  let start;

  const step = (ts) => {
    if (!start) {
      start = ts; // record the first iteration timestamp
    }

    const progress = (ts - start) / timeout; // how far into the time span

    if (progress < 1) {
      el.textContent = Math.floor(num * progress);
      requestAnimationFrame(step); // request the next frame
    } else {
      el.textContent = num; // finish
    }
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

runCounter(6_000_000_000, 3000, document.getElementById("blahblahblah"));
```

```html
<output id="blahblahblah">0</output>
```